# Kali linux сохранение сеанса

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Всем привет, вот такой вопрос например работал в кали на виртуалке virtualbox делал там разные дела, но выключили свет и повторное включение нечего нет.
Можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы сохранялось хотя бы состояние терминала и процесса в нем, хоть не полностью, но что нибудь, как точка восстановление системы?

Comment: бесперебойник есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В виртуалбоксе есть кнопка "сделать снимок" - делает именно то что вы хотели. Со снимка можно возобновить работу. Но эту кнопку надо как-то часто нажимать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если проблема с электричеством, то нужен бесперебойник который держить хотяб минуту. Для бесперебойника ставите программу, а к ней добавляете скрипт который вызывает снапшот на виртуалбоксе.